# How can I manually reset stars in jQuery Stars plugin in jQuery Mobile application?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working on a jQuery Mobile application and I am looking for a way to manually reset stars in jQuery Stars plugin on button click. I tried this:

```
$('input.star').rating('select', false)
```

But it isn't working and producing error:

```
TypeError: $(...).rating is not a function
```

It works fine, if I don't include jQuery Mobile javascript. Is there any way to make it work with jQuery mobile?

I am using following libraries:

- jQuery Star Rating Plugin v3.14
- jQuery 1.9.0
- jQuery Mobile 1.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaScript files should be in following order

1. jQuery 1.9.0
2. jQuery Mobile 1.3.1
3. jQuery Star Rating Plugin v3.14
4. Your script of calling star rating

Comment: worked with this order, but I also had to update the jQuery Star Rating Plugin to version 4.11. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the versions of jquery and jquery mobile that are compatible with the star rating plugin. Also, change the order in which you include jquery and jquery mobile, since it may interfere with the jquery functions used by the star rating.